# html <nav id convert to wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, nav

I am trying to convert this html menu to a nav in wordpress.

```
<nav id="nav-main">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="nav-trigger">
  <span>Menu <img src="img/menu_icon.png" width="40" height="40" alt=""/></span>
</div>
<nav id="nav-mobile"></nav>
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theme functions.php file add this below:

```
function register_header_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_header_menu' );
```

Then paste this part below where you want the navigation to be in the template I'm guess the header.php

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>
```

Add links inside WordPess and style with CSS.